# Creating a Sorted 2D Array from custom Object properties

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a List of objects created from a map like so:

```
Map incomingRequest = (Map)object;
List accounts = (List)incomingRequest.get("accountList");
```

In addition, I loop through these objects and pull them out one by one via the index of that list like so and create the account object:

```
for (int accountRow = 0; accountRow < accounts.size(); accountRow++){
    Account account = (Account)accounts.get(accountRow);
```

There is a method on this `Account account` object that I can use to get an identifier I can sort on called like so: `account.getComp_id().getIcLine()`. This gives me a non-unique number that I can use to group with. I now have a need to do some calculations involving only the grouping ov like `IcLine` properties.

My thought is to create a 2D ArrayList so that I can loop through each sorted array of objects sharing the same `IcLine` number. However, I currently can't figure out exactly how I would do that after googling around and trying to work through it. I feel like this is a good job for recursion, but I can't figure out how to create the 2D ArrayList I need. Your guidance is appreciated